# Decimal columns are rounded when use ROLLUP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rollup

I have a problem when try using ROLLUP in MySQL.

I have a table created like this.

```
create table order_items (
  id int,
  project_name varchar(50),
  order_date date,
  name varchar(20),
  unit_cost decimal(15,3),
  quantity decimal(15,3)
);
```

And inserted data like this

```
insert into order_items (
  id, project_name, order_date, name, unit_cost, quantity
) values (
  1, "project 1", "2021-02-03", "order 1", 229.432, 14.599
);
insert into order_items (
  id, project_name, order_date, name, unit_cost, quantity
) values (
  2, "project 1", "2021-02-04", "order 2", 229.634, 15
);
insert into order_items (
  id, project_name, order_date, name, unit_cost, quantity
) values (
  3, "project 2", "2021-02-04", "order 3", 229.888, 15.543
);
insert into order_items (
  id, project_name, order_date, name, unit_cost, quantity
) values (
  4, "project 1", "2021-02-05", "order 4", 230.543, 1.5
);
insert into order_items (
  id, project_name, order_date, name, unit_cost, quantity
) values (
  5, "project 1", "2021-02-05", "order 5", 229.443, 1.5
);
insert into order_items (
  id, project_name, order_date, name, unit_cost, quantity
) values (
  6, "project 1", "2021-02-03", "order 1", 229.456, 18.234
);
```

I want to aggregate amount = unit_cost * quantity by project for each date, so I use this query with `ROLLUP`, but the unit_cost and quantity columns are rounded in result table. (e.g. unit_cost of first row should be 229.432 but it returns 229)

```
mysql> select order_date, project_name, name, unit_cost, quantity, sum(unit_cost * quantity) as amount from order_items group by order_date, project_name, name, unit_cost, quantity with rollup;
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| order_date | project_name | name    | unit_cost | quantity | amount       |
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| 2021-02-03 | project 1    | order 1 |       229 |       15 |  3349.477768 |
| 2021-02-03 | project 1    | order 1 |       229 |     NULL |  3349.477768 |
| 2021-02-03 | project 1    | order 1 |       229 |       18 |  4183.900704 |
| 2021-02-03 | project 1    | order 1 |       229 |     NULL |  4183.900704 |
| 2021-02-03 | project 1    | order 1 |      NULL |     NULL |  7533.378472 |
| 2021-02-03 | project 1    | NULL    |      NULL |     NULL |  7533.378472 |
| 2021-02-03 | NULL         | NULL    |      NULL |     NULL |  7533.378472 |
...
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+--------------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I remove `ROLLUP`, unit_cost and quantity return to the accurate values.

```
mysql> select order_date, project_name, name, unit_cost, quantity, sum(unit_cost * quantity) as amount from order_items group by order_date, project_name, name, unit_cost, quantity;
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| order_date | project_name | name    | unit_cost | quantity | amount      |
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 2021-02-03 | project 1    | order 1 |   229.432 |   14.599 | 3349.477768 |
| 2021-02-04 | project 1    | order 2 |   229.634 |   15.000 | 3444.510000 |
| 2021-02-04 | project 2    | order 3 |   229.888 |   15.543 | 3573.149184 |
| 2021-02-05 | project 1    | order 4 |   230.543 |    1.500 |  345.814500 |
| 2021-02-05 | project 1    | order 5 |   229.443 |    1.500 |  344.164500 |
| 2021-02-03 | project 1    | order 1 |   229.456 |   18.234 | 4183.900704 |
+------------+--------------+---------+-----------+----------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there any way to use `ROLLUP` but keep the accurate values for grouping columns of decimal types?

MySQL version is 8.0.21.

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE, not partial description. Provide sample data as INSERT INTO, not as query output.

Comment: It works fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1c8f2a5e60b1036c0c0955095e9cfbe4

Answer (score 0):

After trying version 8.0.20, 8.0.22, 8.0.23, I found that this problem is a bug introduced in version 8.0.21 and has been fixed in 8.0.23.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-23.html

> Certain group by queries that performed correctly did not return the expected result when WITH ROLLUP was added. This was due to the fact that decimal information was not always correctly piped through rollup group items, causing functions returning decimal values such as TRUNCATE() to receive data of the wrong type. (Bug #101684, Bug #32179240)